# Lifetime of a WIMP

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, wimps

I have been watching videos of WIMP's and have a simple question..

The larger the particles, the shorter their lifetime.  A top quark is so massive that it cannot form a "stable" bond with any other particle to form a meson or baryon.

If WIMPS are too massive to make in a particle accelerator, how can they still be around today to affect gravity of galaxies?  Wouldn't they have decayed by now into things we could see or detect?

Comment: have you read this ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particle . Theories are looking for stable wimps.

Comment: *The larger the particles, the shorter their lifetime.* It isn’t that simple. The lifetime depends on interaction strengths, possible decay products, etc. The proton is a lot heavier than, say, a muon, but it has an infinite lifetime as far as we know whereas a muon decays in two microseconds.

Comment: Also [Why should dark matter be stable (i.e., non-decaying)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353124/why-should-dark-matter-be-stable-i-e-non-decaying) and [How did dark matter become a relic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319404/how-did-dark-matter-become-a-relic)